# exposed to the alleged causes

Tags: meaning, idioms

From this passage, 
None of the attempts to specify the causes of crime
explains why most of the **people exposed to the
alleged causes** do not commit crimes and, conversely,
why so many of those not so exposed have.

To me the bold sentence means "people who are alleged". Am I correct? I'm so skeptical about the way of using this kind of structure.

Thank you so much,

Comment: No. *Alleged* modifies *causes*, not *people*.  "Alleged causes" is a shorthand way of saying "factors which are alleged to be causes [of crime]". Most people exposed to these factors do not commit crimes, while many people who **are** exposed to these factors **do** commit crimes, both of which challenge the causal relationship which is alleged.

Comment: Try reading it like this: most of the people **who are** exposed to the alleged causes... If you understand that, then you understand what the sentence means without "who are".

Comment: @StoneyB - your comment seems the most appropriate. Why not post it as an answer? :-)

Comment: @Phylyp Because while I was recomposing this as a detailed Answer, somebody else came along and posted an Answer which said everything I intended to say.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is saying three things:

Some people have attempted to specify things that make people commit crimes (causes).

Nobody has attempted to explain why most people who deal with these things (the causes) do not commit crimes. That is the bold part of your sentence. The *alleged* part refers to the causes. They are only alleged because it is impossible to prove their link to crime.

The final part says nobody has attempted to explain why people commit crimes when they have not been exposed to any of the things (causes).